# Tag merge: [powerline-networking] and [ethernet-over-power]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

There are

- 16 questions tagged [powerline-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerline-networking)
- 7 with [homeplug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homeplug)
- 6 with [ethernet-over-power](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ethernet-over-power)

[powerline-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerline-networking) and [ethernet-over-power](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ethernet-over-power) should be merged into [powerline-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerline-networking), I believe – although technically you could run some non-Ethernet layer 2 protocol over a powerline network, I don't think that's available on the market.

[homeplug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homeplug) is by far the most popular powerline networking technology (27 hits for the keyword on Super User).  It's probably not right to merge with [powerline-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerline-networking) but perhaps it would be good if the [homeplug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/homeplug) tag wiki also linked to [powerline-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerline-networking)?

Background: [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication#Home_networking_.28LAN.29)

Comment: Note: If you want tag wikis to link to other tags, you can always [write or improve one](http://superuser.com/edit-tag-wiki/3096)!

Comment: Done - my edits are now pending review for the [tag:homeplug] wiki.  If people agree, maybe someone could do the merge suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Good idea -- I went ahead and merged all these (with synonyms) into [powerline-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powerline-networking).